# Unity detect left/right/up/down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am implementing my code on an object and the player's hand is the origin to detect if it is in the direction of right/left/up/down.

So far the code is working to detect all 4 axis but there is a problem.
If the direction is left/right, it prints both "Left" and "Up", similarly "Right" and "Up". Can it be just "Left" or "Right" and not print the y axis along with it?

How do I fix this?

```
public GameObject playersHand;
private Transform targetOrigin;
private Vector2 targetPos;
private Vector2 mypos;

void Start()
{
    targetOrigin = this.gameObject.transform;
}

void Update()
{
    mypos = playersHand.transform.position;
    targetPos = targetOrigin.position;

    if (targetOrigin.position.x < mypos.x && changed(mypos.y, targetPos.y))
    {
        print ("Right");
    }
    else if (changed(mypos.y, targetPos.y))
    {
        print ("Left");
    }

    if (targetOrigin.position.y < mypos.y && changed(mypos.x, targetPos.x))
    {
        print ("Up");
    }
    else if (changed(mypos.x, targetPos.x))
    {
        print ("Down");
    }
}

bool changed(float a, float b)
{
    if ((int)a == (int)b)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds somehow faulty... Can you specify what happens if you press up, does it print anything else then up?

Comment: yea it actually prints "Up" and "Left" if the player's hand is to left of the object, similarly it prints right if it is right of the object.

Comment: Try to print the actual values of both transform positions. I think because it is a float the chance that these values will be exact the same is very small. You could try if this is the problem, to round the positions to a specific size so there will be some kind of tolerance.

Comment: How do you mean i do that? Can you please explain with the current code?

Comment: Use Debug.Log(the transform.position you want to see); press play and look into the console of the editor

Comment: Did it helped you? Or do you need some more guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is logic.
you need to check if the position is in the horizontal direction.
that should work:

```
if (targetOrigin.position.x < mypos.x && Mathf.Abs(mypos.x - targetPos.x) > Mathf.Abs(mypos.y - targetPos.y))
{
    print ("Right");
}
else if (Mathf.Abs(mypos.x - targetPos.x) > Mathf.Abs(mypos.y - targetPos.y))
{
    print ("Left");
}

if (targetOrigin.position.y < mypos.y && Mathf.Abs(mypos.y - targetPos.y) > Mathf.Abs(mypos.x - targetPos.x))
{
    print ("Up");
}
else if (Mathf.Abs(mypos.y - targetPos.y) > Mathf.Abs(mypos.x - targetPos.x))
{
    print ("Down");
}
```